How do you add a WebTunnel Bridge in the torcc file in linux? - Kali Linux preferably!
How do you add a WebTunnel Bridge in the torcc file in linux? - Kali Linux preferably, Thanks!

Kali Linux is a Debian loaded with additional packages, so just follow the Debian tutorials and you will be fine. Look at /etc/tor folder and add it as usual
